# Independence in conditional expectation of martingales

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, martingales

I am stuck in a problem and would appreciate any guidance/ hints.

We denote $\mathcal F_t$ as such:
if $X_t$ is a stochastic process, the minimum amount of information resulted from knowing the process $X_s$ until time $t$ is denoted by $\mathcal F_t = \sigma(X_s: s \leq t)$. This is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the events $\{\mathcal w:X_s(\mathcal w)\in(a,b)\}$ for any real numbers $a < b$ and $s \leq t$

This is the question:
Let $X_n, \, n\geq 0$ be a sequence of independent, integrable random variables such that $E[X_n] = 1$ for n $\geq 0$. Prove that $P_n = X_0X_1\cdots X_n$ is an $\mathcal F_n$-martingale.

I have established $P_n$ is integrable, and is also $\mathcal F_n$-measurable. However, I am stuck in showing $$X_n = E[X_t|\mathcal F_n]\quad\forall\, n < t$$

By any chance is $E[X_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n]=E[X_{n+k}]$ for all natural number $k$? This is the part I can't quite figure out.

- Let's suppose $E[X_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n]=E[X_{n+k}]$ is true. That means $X_{n+k}$ is independent of $\mathcal F_n = \sigma(X_0, X_1,\cdots, X_n)$. I suspect this is related to the given fact that $X_n$ is a sequence of independent random variables but I cannot see how.

If it is, then my thought process would be: 
$$E[P_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n] = E[P_nX_{n+1}\cdots X_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n] = P_nE[X_{n+1}\cdots X_{n+k}|\mathcal F_n] = P_nE[X_{n+1}]\cdots E[X_{n+k}] = P_n$$

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}|F_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}]$ since $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are independent, and your reasoning after that is correct. So you are doing it well.

Comment: @Alfredo Thanks, but I'm still unsure, even after the fact that $\{X_n\}_{n \in\mathbb N}$ are independent. So what if they are independent?

Comment: $X_{n+k}$ is independent of $X_1, X_2, \ldots , X_n \implies X_{n+k}$ is independent of $\sigma (X_1,X_2, \ldots ,X_n) \implies X_{n+k}$ is independent of $F_n$, and there is the property that if $Y$ and $F$ are independent, then $\mathbb{E}[Y|F]=\mathbb{E}[Y]$. So $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}|F_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}]$.

Comment: @Alfredo Thank you for the clarification! I was not sure about "if $X_{n+k}$ is independent of $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ then $X_{n+k}$ is independent of $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n)$".

Comment: No problem. From the definition of the conditional expectation you can observe that $\mathbb{E}[Y|\sigma(X)]=\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$ and use that, so $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}|F_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}|X_1,X_2,\ldots ,X_n]$ and using the independence, that is equal to $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}]$